# MySQL SUM() in step by step column for incomes

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Database: `name_ allmoney`

Table name: `MONEY`

```
+-----+--------+------------+---------+---------+
| id  | name   | date       | income  | account |
+-----+--------+------------+---------+---------+
|  1  | Ann    | 01.01.2012 | 100     | 100     |
|  2  | Matt   | 02.01.2012 | 100     | 200     |
|  3  | Tom    | 03.01.2012 | 100     | 300     |
|  4  | Peter  | 04.01.2012 | 100     | 400     |
+-----+--------+------------+---------+---------+
```

Hello Stackoverflowers! ;)

I'm newbie for MySQL... Last week I've spend searchin for solution for above situation. I'm tryin to create script summing income column, but not only showing the sum of the column like

> SELECT *, SUM(kasa) from MONEY GROUP BY id;

but I have to add new column called account, which has the option like my excel sheet:

```
accout1st row =income1+account1
accout2nd row =income2+account1
accout3rd row =income3+account2
accout4th row =income4+account3
```

Is there any code or possibility to create column like **account**  in MySQL or PHP?

```
CREATE TABLE money (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    income DECIMAL(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    numer_kluczyka INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    name CHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    za_co CHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    account INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a user variable -

```
SELECT @m := 0;

SELECT
    id,
    name,
    date,
    income,
    @m := @m + income AS balance
FROM money
ORDER BY date ASC, id ASC;
```

The order by should use the primary key for the table.

Splitting the two queries in your PHP should fix the problem -

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass') or die('failed to connect');
mysql_select_db("album", $connection) or die('failed to select db');

mysql_query("SELECT @m:=0;");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, imie_i_nazwisko, data_wplaty, kasa, @m := @m + income AS balance FROM money ORDER BY data_wplaty ASC , id ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['income'] . " " . $row['balance'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thank You all for Your important notice and useful solutions. The nnichols answer gave me the result I was looking for, however now I need to figure it out how to ALETER my existing Column and add  to it above properties or create additional one called balance.

Comment: I think you need to better explain what you are trying to achieve. Adding the DDL (SHOW CREATE TABLE `MONEY`) for your table would also help us to help you.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `money` 
( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`income` decimal(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`numer_kluczyka` int(111) DEFAULT NULL, , 
`name` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL, /* this column is my: "name" 
`za_co` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL, /* not important
`account` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) /* for now doing no action.
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=10 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: In other words Your script is great, now  I'm tryin to echo this table. However my SQL/PHP skill is a problem.
mysql_select_db("album", $conection);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT @m:=0;

SELECT 
id, 
imie_i_nazwisko, 
data_wplaty, 
kasa, @m := @m + income AS balance
FROM money
ORDER BY data_wplaty ASC , id ASC
");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['income'] . " " . $row['balance'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

gives an error:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource i

Comment: You will need to run the two queries separately as the old mysql functions do not support multiple queries, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Please delete this last comment and post this in with the main question. That way it can be formatted properly.

Comment: Once again I want to help You for your quides solution! All works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply need to store the sum computed so far in your php loop.

Something like:

```
$account = null;
while(($result = /* read mysql result */)) {
    if (is_null($account)) { // Handle first row
        $account = $result['income'];
    }
    // Show first columns
    echo $result['id'], $result['income'], $account;
    $account += $result['income'];
}
```

Comment: I read the OP as wanting to sum the past income _for each person_, in which case you need to make your `$account` variable an array.

Comment: In that case I think you misunderstood the OP as the excel sheet example seems to show totalling for all records not per user.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit unclear, but if I've guessed what you want correctly, you could do this with a subselect that sums the `income` column over all rows up to the current row:

```
SELECT id, name, date, income,
  ( SELECT SUM(income) FROM money AS b
    WHERE b.id = a.id
      AND b.date <= a.date
  ) AS balance
FROM money AS a
```

You could also do the same with a join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.date, a.income, SUM(b.income) AS balance
FROM money AS a
  JOIN money AS b ON (b.id = a.id AND b.date <= a.date)
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.date, a.income
```

(The `GROUP BY` is supposed to be on the primary key of the `money` table.  It's not entirely clear from your question what the primary key is supposed to be, since it doesn't seem to be `id`.)

Also note that both of these answers assume that the `date` columns are unique for each `id` and sort in ascending order by time, so that the condition `b.date <= a.date` can find all rows up to and including the current row.  If that's not the case, you should either fix your table so that it is, or adjust the query accordingly.

---

Edit: [S0pra's PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9556083) will work too.  However, the way I read your question, what you want is to sum the past income for each `id` separately.  If so, you can use S0pra's code with a few modifications:

```
$balance = array();
while ( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {  // or equivalent
    $id = $result['id'];
    if ( array_key_exists( $id, $balance ) ) {
        $balance[$id] += $result['income'];
    } else {
        $balance[$id] = $result['income'];  // handle first row for this id
    }
    $result['balance'] = $balance[$id];
    // do something with $result here
}
```